# How do I check if I am in a graphical environment on a Mac using bash?

Tags: bash, terminal, osx

I am trying to determine whether or not I am in a graphical environment via bash on a Mac.

The goal is to have an if/else structure within a bash script that can handle these two cases.

**Case 1**: I can open windows from the command-line.

**Case 2**: I cannot open windows from the command-line.

Comment: You could check whether Finder is running (via `ps`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's enough to check whether Finder is running, you may use

```
if pgrep -qx Finder; then
    echo 'Finder is running'
else
    echo 'Finder is not running'
fi
```

If you are running some X server (not commonly the case on macOS), and want to check whether the current session is attached to it,

```
if [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
    echo 'In X'
else
    echo 'Not in X'
fi
```

Both of these tests are quite naive but would at least cover the most basic situations.

Comment: Probably needs `pgrep -xq Finder`, I got two matches without `-x`. Or even `pgrep -qx -u $(id -u) Finder`. But as long as the OP doesn't clarify why they need to be able to distinguish this it's not clear whether this is enough.

Comment: @nohillside Yes, `-x` may be needed (added that). I'll hold of with further tinkering until we get further feedback.